# Actualizar modelo ADO.net C#

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber cómo se actualiza un modelo de ADO.NET ya que me vi en la necesidad de actualizar mi base de datos pero el proyecto en Visual Studio C# me dice que necesita, por eso quisiera saber la forma más fácil de actualizar el modelo.

[image: ME sale este error al tratar correr el proyecto]

Esta línea es la que sulta el error es donde mando a llamar una tabla para que se muestre en un `DropDownList`:

```
public Array cargarCategorias() 
{ 
    return (MI.Categoria.Select(x => x.sNombre).ToArray()); //es aqui 
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código con el cual intentas hacer el `UPDATE`?

Comment: Aún no sé como hacer el update.. sólo intenté correr el proyecto ya con la BD actualizada desde SQL SERVER y me da ese erorr al intentar entrar al formulario de dónde utilizo los registros que me traigo desde SQL...

Comment: Bueno, ese error te lo tira en cierta línea, ese es el segmento de código que requiero ver para saber qué está pasando con tu código ;)

Comment: public Array cargarCategorias()
        {
            return (MI.Categoria.Select(x => x.sNombre).ToArray()); //es aqui
        }

Esta línea es la que sulta el error es dónde mando a llamar una tabla para que se muestre en un combo box

Comment: @EricMtz, **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y mira [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).

Comment: Nota: por esta ocasión he [editado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/109437/edit) la pregunta añadiendo todos los elementos necesarios para que obtenga mayor atención. Para lograr esto, sugiero que tomes el [tour] y de igual forma revises [ask] para que sepas cómo se maneja esta gran comunidad :D

Answer (score 0):

Este error se debe a un cambio en tu modelo de datos, ya sea que lo modificaste o agregaste componentes en tu solución, o en su caso, la base de datos sufrió modificaciones en su estructura y los cambios no concuerdan con las definiciones de Entity Framework.

Para solucionarlo debes identificar la clase donde se inicializa tu base de datos, si tu modelo de datos se llama `DataContext`, entonces la podrás encontrar como `DataContextInitializer`, y luego implementar de [`System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
public class DataContextInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
    {
        SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
        context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<DataContext>());
    }
}
```

Con esto, si tu modelo de datos ha sufrido algún cambio, se estaría forzando a recrear la base de datos para poder consistencia de objetos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es anticlick en el model.edmx y validar, te saldran los errores, visualmente los eliminas de las tablas o haces lo q quieras hasta que te funcione. y si quieres actualizar dale update y seleccionas las tablas que quieras de tu modelo.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/389321)